# How to check that a PDF file has some link with Ruby/Rspec?

Tags: ruby, pdf, rspec, pdf-generation

I am using [prawnpdf/pdf-inspector](https://github.com/prawnpdf/pdf-inspector) to test that content of a PDF generated in my Rails app is correct.

I would want to check that the PDF file contains a link with certain URL. I looked at [yob/pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) but haven't found any useful information related to this topic

Is it possible to test URLs within PDF with Ruby/RSpec?

I would want the following:

```
expect(urls_in_pdf(pdf)).to include 'https://example.com/users/1'
```

Comment: what is exactly the problem you are facing? since you use `pdf-inspector` you have the whole text of the pdf right?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I would want to check that a link included into the PDF has correct HREF

Comment: yeah then shouldn't you be able to just search for the `<a href='url'>` tag in the text?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo pdf-inspector and pdf-reader cannot read href from a PDF content. If a PDF contains a link like `<a href='url'>URL</a>` pdf readers return only URL in the parsed text

Answer (score 2):

The https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader contains a method for each page called text.
Do something like

```
    pdf = PDF::Reader.new("tmp/pdf.pdf")
    assert pdf.pages[0].text.include? 'https://example.com/users/1'
```

assuming what you are looking for is at the first page

Answer (score 0):

Since `pdf-inspector` seems only to return text, you could try to use the [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) directly (`pdf-inspector` uses it anyways).

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new("somefile.pdf")

reader.pages.each do |page|
  puts page.raw_content # This should also give you the link
end
```

Anyway I only did a quick look at the github page. I am not sure what `raw_content` exactly returns. But there is also a low-level method to directly access the objects of the pdf:

```
reader  = PDF::Reader.new("somefile.pdf")
puts reader.objects.inspect
```

With that it surely is possible to get the url.